# Where is World hillshade free download?

Tags: raster, data, hillshade

i need world hillshade with resolution about 1x1 km.

Do you know where i can it download ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It got flagged for low quality, which it probably is. However since downloading a 1km DEM and running a GIS application over it is a possible solution, I'm leaning to keeping it open.

Answer (score 12):

Three of the first sources that come to mind:

- [OSM hillshade basemap](http://download.osmand.net/hillshade/)
- [USGS NED hillshade basemap](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/usgs-hill-shade-base-map-service-from-the-national-map)
- [ESRI hillshade basemap (based on SRTM 30m)](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3cedfc19d7b941d89ee15b0e2f454070)

Or you could always [download the free SRTM 30m data](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) and [create the hillshade yourself](https://developmentseed.org/blog/2009/jul/30/using-open-source-tools-make-elevation-maps-afghanistan-and-pakistan/).

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to @Kersten's brilliant answer, you can download [Elevation maps of Europe](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/digital-elevation-model-of-europe) which includes 1km x 1km hillshade data:

[image: 1km x 1km hillshade data for Europe]

---

Additionally, there's also a [Global Hillshades compressed raster](http://librarygeodata.gmu.edu/WLMS.html) which I believe is based on SRTM 90m data:

[image: Global hillshade data]

Comment: +1, didn't know about the EEA data&maps portal. Nice find.